# Azure data factory says temp table is an "Invalid object name"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a very large query that I am attempting to use in a Copy Data Azure Data Factory (ADF) workflow.  This is a simplified version of it:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
    (
        Name VARCHAR(255)
        ,… --some other fields
    );
    INSERT INTO #tmp
    (
      Name
  ,… --some other fields
    )
    EXECUTE sp_getData


    SELECT t.Name
FROM #tmp AS t
    
BEGIN TRY 
    DROP TABLE #tmp 
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH 
END CATCH
```

When I specify this query as my "Source" for my ADF copy workflow it immediately displays the error:

> A database operation failed with the following error: 'Invalid object
>   name '#tmp'.' Invalid object name '#tmp'.,
>   SqlErrorNumber=208,Class=16,State=0, . Activity ID:
>   707769bc-a864-4e15-8217-bec1ef9462bb

If I run this query directly in SSMS it executes fine with no errors displayed at all.  But if I'm in the ADF creation wizard and I click the "Validate" button, it displays the error message, displays "loading preview" for a while and then returns data as expected.  If I try to click "Next" to continue on with the Copy Data setup it will not let me continue.  Unfortunately it doesn't not seem to specify which line in the query is causing the error so I'm not exactly sure where the problem lies.

Why would I be getting this error in ADF but not in SSMS itself?  I'm using the same account to execute the query and I can't see any differences other than one is being run from ADF and one is being run directly from SSMS.  Is this a limitation of ADF? How can I fix this?

Comment: Does it need to be a temp table? I guess it's simply validating the query and not actually running it. I suggest you populate a permanent table in a prior step and just select from it in the data flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally the #temp table are created in tempdb , but then Linked service is pointing to a specified DB and so this error .

Please use the table variable @temp table and it will work just fine .

Comment: Perfect, I chage #TMP to @TMP and work perfectly.